# How to pass value inside static method in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, static, static-methods

I need to pass value inside a static method

Here globals values are giving null value to the static method

```
static Future<void> sendLocation() async {
  var param = {
    'api_key': globals.api_key,
    'actionto': 'task',
    'customer_id': globals.customer_id,
    'user_id': globals.user_id,
  };
  print(globals.user_id);
}
```

Output == null

whereas when I try to print inside initstate it gives the actual value

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  print(globals.user_id);
}
```

output == 227

Comment: How is `globals` defined? Can you show the whole class?

Comment: @julemand101Just not consider the globals. Even if it is a simple variable also it will give null value.